# How to center an image in a table td?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center (center+middle) an image, and the title inside h2, in a table column (td)

CSS

```
.centered
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td class="centered"><%= image_tag(prank.image_url, :size => "50x50") %></td>
    <td class="centered"><h2><%=prank.category.titleize%></h2></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: text-align:center might work.

Comment: if u dont got ans yet then will you please share live link of this error....

Answer (score 28):

You could try:

```
.centered { vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; }
.centered img { display:block; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: this worked for me! thanks!

full line:
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;"><img style="height: 60px; display:block; margin:0 auto;" src="{{ item.image_url }}" alt=""></td>

Answer (score 2):

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/k6Nvk/1/

just add in your `<td>` >> `<td align="center" valign="middle"><image path></td>`

and you can also do this using css check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k6Nvk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.centered{width: 50px; margin: 0px, auto, 0px, auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is declare margin from left and right (top and bottom optional):

```
.center {
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
}
```

Or you can just use

```
.center
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 20%;
}
```

If you don't have to just don't use `<table>` tag. Use `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.
I call the base twitter css file.
than after i call my default css file
in my default file I have this class

```
.table-center th, .table-center td {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

then in my table i do this:

```
<table class="table table-center ....">...</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

N.B. **align="center"** is not supported in HTML 5; see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp

Answer (score 1):

### This should work

```
.cntr
{
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

```
<div class="cntr" style="width: 130px">
         <img src="me.jpg" alt="me"  style="width: 130px" />
</div>
```

Comment: margin 0 auto should be for img tag

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, but not 100% sure if it'll work:

```
.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is close but it will not work unless you specify a fixed width.

Answer (score -1):

I would try `text-align: center;` in inline style="".